# onCreateViewHolder not calling in fragmnet recyclerview

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-adapter

I am using recyclerview in fragmnet.
Fragmnet is working but my recycler view data not dispalyed.
**My xml code:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/projectcommends" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/white" android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="@dimen/common_padding">
        <TextView style="@style/TextHeading" android:text="Project comments" />
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <TextView android:layout_width="180dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Date" android:textSize="17dp" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView android:layout_width="180dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Comments" android:textSize="17dp" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/commendsList" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Row xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
<TextView android:id="@+id/commentdate" android:layout_width="180dp" android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="20-06-2016" android:gravity="center" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/commentdetail" android:layout_width="180dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="15dp" android:text="project commends testing list" android:gravity="center" />
```

**My Fragmnet code:**

```
public class ProjectComments extends Fragment {
   private List < CommentsData > arraylist;
   private RecyclerView recyclerView;
   private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
   private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
   private String ordered;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_comments, container, false);
      initialize(view);
      Bundle b = getArguments();
      orderid = b.getString("orderid");
      recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
      arraylist = new ArrayList < > ();
      adapter = new CommentsAdapter(arraylist);
      recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
      getCommentsData();
      return view;
   }

   private void initialize(View view) {
      recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.commendsList);
   }

   private void getCommentsData() {
      String mobilecustomertoken = SharedPreferencesManager.readPreferenceString("MobileCustomerToken", "D/N");
      JSONObject commentData = new JSONObject();
      try {
         commentData.put("mobilecustomertoken", mobilecustomertoken);
         commentData.put("orderid", orderid);
         JsonObjectRequest commentsObject = new JsonObjectRequest(1, Common.CommentsList, commentData, new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject commentsResponse) {
               Log.d("Responsedetail", commentsResponse.toString());
               try {
                  int status = commentsResponse.getInt("status");
                  if (status == 1) {
                     commentsProgress(commentsResponse);
                  }
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
         }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               error.printStackTrace();
               Log.d("Response", "PENDING ERROR");
            }
         });
         commentsObject.setShouldCache(false);
         ServiceBellApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(commentsObject);
      } catch (JSONException localJSONException) {
         localJSONException.printStackTrace();
         return;
      }
   }

   private void commentsProgress(JSONObject commentsResponse) throws JSONException, InterruptedException {
      JSONArray result = commentsResponse.getJSONArray("response");
      CommentsData orderListModule;
      for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
         JSONObject jsonObject = result.getJSONObject(i);
         orderListModule = new CommentsData();
         orderListModule.setCommentsData(jsonObject.getString("commentdate"));
         orderListModule.setCommentsDetail(jsonObject.getString("comendDetail"));
         arraylist.add(orderListModule);
      }
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      int count = adapter.getItemCount();
      if (count != 0) {
         Log.d("Response", "Test");
      }
   }
}
```

**Final my adapter code:**

```
public class CommentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < CommentsAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder > {
   List < CommentsData > arrayList;
   public CommentsAdapter(List < CommentsData > list) {
      this.arrayList = list;
   }

   @Override
   public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comments_list, parent, false);
      RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
      return recyclerViewHolder;
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
      CommentsData commentsData = arrayList.get(position);
      Log.d("ResponseAdapter", commentsData.getCommentsData());
      holder.commentdate.setText(commentsData.getCommentsData());
      holder.commentDetail.setText(commentsData.getCommentsDetail());
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
      String dd = Integer.toString(arrayList.size());Log.d("Responsecount", dd);return (null != arrayList ? arrayList.size() : 0);
   }

   public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      public TextView commentdate, commentDetail;
      public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
         super(itemView);
         Log.d("ResponseAda", "Success");
         commentdate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentdate);
         commentDetail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentdetail);
      }
   }
}
```

**Edited:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_comments, container, false);
    initialize(view);
    Bundle b = getArguments();
    orderid = b.getString("orderid");
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new
            LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    arraylist = new ArrayList < > ();
    getCommentsData();
    adapter = new CommentsAdapter(arraylist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

Any one please help me why my onCreateViewHolder function not calling?

Comment: Do u have data in arraylist which you are setting to ur adapter?

Comment: Yes i have arraylist data. getCount is 1

Comment: Can u try this recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); put this line before calling adapter.notifyDatasetChanged and try once

Comment: Did u try @Haroon's answer?

Comment: Hmm yes but not working

Comment: Can u put a break point at getItemCount() in adapter and tell me what is it returning?

Comment: I get Responsecount: 1 value

Comment: Can u post your updated fragment code with the changes you have done now?

Comment: I updated my code. Just i print my count in log

Comment: Didn't get much help with that. Do one thing can u replace your entire  onCreateView method with Haroon's onCreateView method. And post your layout xml.

Comment: I added my new onCreateView code and xml code already i added

Comment: keep Haroon's method and can u please remove everything inside the cardview except recyclerview with height "match-parent" and try?

Comment: or do one thing change "projectcommends" linear layout height to match_parent and try

Comment: My cardview is displayed, but recyclerview only not working

Comment: One try can u change the LinearLayout height to wrap_content in Row xml and check once?

Answer (score 0):

Can you Place Replace the above code snip and recheck , i guess you're not passing the data to while setting it , clog the data set you trying to set to adapter

```
  @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_comments, container, false);
  initialize(view);
  Bundle b = getArguments();
  orderid = b.getString("orderid");
  recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new  
  LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
  arraylist = new ArrayList < > ();
  getCommentsData();
  adapter = new CommentsAdapter(arraylist);
  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  return view;
```

}

Comment: Have you Check the data before setting to adapter is it even there ?